# Is there any built-in alternatives to cron in MySQL or other databases?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

It's pretty basic what I'm asking.

Imagine a column for date in users table.

```
Username --- RegistrationDate ----- Authority
user1     -  (today's date)     -   1
user2     -  (yesterday's date) -   1
```

Each user has to be upgraded to `Authority = 2` after 10 days automatically.

I know I can do this with PHP by executing it constantly with CRON, but what about built-in features of databases?

Something like:

```
//pseudo code
bind trigger on users.RegistrationDate, function() {
       if(RegistrationDate >= RegistrationDate+10 days)
           return updateAuthority(1)
}
```

One important thing about this is the performance. It shouldn't check for each trigger in a loop, whatever should be triggered should be triggered right on time by binding them directly on the column.

Second important thing is, it should be exported when I take a backup of the database. I don't want to re-create them all.

I'm not an expert about databases, but I use MySQL for this project and need a similar feature for MySQL. If it doesn't exists and I have to continue using a cron, would you please tell me if similar feature exists in Oracle/MSSQL or PostgreSQL so I can port my database? (oh, and MongoDB too, it may also be an alternative.)

Thank you.

Comment: My question is probably wrong but my answer isn't on the topic above. Events doesn't fullfill my pseudo code question, also, as stated above, I'm not looking for features which loops and executes events on time basis. I want to bind things directly on columns and looking for a similar feature. How is using global time based events or jobs duplicates this question I'm wondering.

Comment: Why do you need such feature? Your logic is straight forward. After 10 days, assume that authority = 2. Why do you need to run any jobs that do it? However, if you want db/event/job managed solution - assume that midnight of the day when user registered is the orientation point, and then your query from within a single event becomes trivial. If date + 10 days >= actual date, update authority to 2. It's the least overhead you can imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL you have events:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html

Just create an event which is triggered every day and updates Authority.

**EDIT:** (to answer a question below)

I'm sure the wizard exports events, but if it doesn't, you can use the `mysqldump` program (it's in the bin directory). You can also use the `SHOW CREATE EVENT` command to export a single event: it returns the SQL command you need to re-create the event.

Comment: Do they export with export wizard?

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server have the Sql Server Agent. It's a process that run jobs at the specified time. Jobs  are formed by steps, and one step can be a Sql Query, or an SSIS package, or executing a program and so on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Comment: Oracle has this too (dbms_jobs).

Comment: So they're just basically built-in crons?

Comment: Well, in the case of Sql Server it's like an advanced an DDBB oriented cron.

Comment: What about my pseudo feature? Is that not possible using databases? Would be a better solution than jobs for my case.

Comment: If you only have this requirement, maybe SQL Server is a bit too much, but if chances are of growing in the future, then I recommend to switch to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has dbms_scheduler (dbms_job is deprecated).

Features include

- custom schedules (e.g. every 5 minutes, every Monday to Friday at 18:00, ...)
- job chains (dependencies among jobs)
- disabling / enabling jobs at will
- running jobs interactively (used mostly for debugging purposes)

Example (run system monitoring every day at 22:00):

```
 begin
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'JOB_SYSTEM_MONITORING'
     ,job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
     ,job_action => 'begin my_schema.system_monitoring.checkAndSendEMails; end; '
     ,start_date => to_date('2013-04-29 04:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
     ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=22'
     ,enabled => TRUE
     ,comments => 'System monitoring (daily job, runs at 22:00.');
   end;
```